# Auth0 login for Microsoft Teams application

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams, auth0, auth0-lock

We are using auth0 (auth0.com) authentication for our application today.
Its an Angular 9 application using Auth0Lock from the auth0-lock package.

Now we need to integrate our application with Microsoft Teams, as an Microsoft Teams app.
However, we do not know how to get the authentication working for our application in Teams using auth0.
We are specifically interested in the flow that authenticates a user in a Microsoft Teams tab.

Are there any guides or instructions for this, or does anyone have knowledge about how to do it?

I have read the Microsofts instructions for the authentication process, but that uses Azure AD as auth provider, and we would prefer to not replace auth0 with that because that would be a huge job replacing our auth provider:
[Authenticate a user in a Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad#navigate-to-the-authorization-page-from-your-popup-page)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad#navigate-to-the-authorization-page-from-your-popup-page).

In authorizeEndpoint, instead of setting the login.microsoft.com you could provide your own auth provider login link.

Comment: Do I also need to replace the properties of queryParams with the properties required by my own auth provider?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace the properties of queryParams.